# Need help splicing a list

Tags: python, loops, splice

I have a list of, say, size 144. I need every 16 elements to be stored in a 2-D array. In the end I would want to have a 16x9 2-D array. How do I pull these elements out in a loop and rearrange them? Here is what I have so far...

```
yuH = np.zeros([N, t])
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(len(p)):
        print(p[0+j:16+j])
        yuH[:,i] = p[0+j:16+j] # change to N
        j = j + 16
```

Where N in this case is 16 and t is 9. p is my list of 144. yuH is the matrix I am trying to create. alas it is not working...
I get the ValueError "setting an array element with a sequence" at the line yuH[:,i] = p[0+j:16+j] after many runs.

Something like...

```
p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

p = [[1,  [5,  9,  [13, [17, 
      2,   6,  10,  14,  18, 
      3,   7,  11,  15,  19, 
      4],  8]  12], 16], 20]]
```

Comment: What is `p`? Your list?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a smaller matrix, e.g. 3x2, along with sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input and sample output based on that input

Comment: Sounds like you need to play with [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape), [np.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) or [np.ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

Comment: @MarkSnyder Yes! Sorry.

Comment: @Alexander I don't really have an expected result per say, just need to reorganize my list p into a 2-D matrix somehow. But I am trouble shooting as we speak.

Comment: So, assuming you want a 3x2 matrix for example, then `p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` would result in `yuH = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`? Also, is `p` a list or a numpy array (you haven't tagged the question as numpy and you mentioned a list).

Comment: Well not quite actually. In that case, the first column of the matrix needs to be the first 3 elements of the list, p. The second column of the matrix would then be the last 3 elements. There would be only two columns and three rows. Sorry I tried to give an example in the comments but I couldn't get it formatted correctly.
@Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is just reorganize you array `p` you can just do this:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 16
t = 9
p = np.arange(t*N) # example array p

yuH = p.reshape([t,N])

print(yuH.shape)

>>> (9, 16)

print(yuH)

>>> 
[[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15]
 [ 16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31]
 [ 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47]
 [ 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63]
 [ 64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79]
 [ 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95]
 [ 96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111]
 [112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127]
 [128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143]]
```

Comment: Does that do it in the right order though? Order really matters in this case. Is the first column the first 16 elements of the list, the second column the next 16 elements and so on? I can't tell because they are all ones.

Comment: @becs edited the answer so you can check it's true that it keeps order.

Comment: hmmmm, not quite. I'm looking more for the first 16 elements of the list needs to be the first column. Not the first 9 needs to be the first row ya feel?

Comment: @becs my bad, i understood the opposite, check it out.

Comment: Awesome that works because I can just transpose it after that. Thank you!!!